# Scheduling tasks in parallel on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, scheduled-tasks

I have N = 128 (say) tasks, `task 0`, `task 1`, ... `task N-1`, that I need to complete. Each task will take an unknown amount of time to complete, and they may be completed in any order. I am on a machine that has a large number of cores, but I only want to run 16 of these tasks at a time. Is there a utility for automating this?

I considered

```
$ for i in {0..127}; do nice -n 19 ./task $i & done;
```

but this would run all of the tasks at the same time. Rather, I would like something that will start the first 16 tasks, and then substitute in a new one whenever a task finishes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use GNU Parallel:

  ```
  $ parallel -j16 ./task ::: {0..127}
  ```
- Use Moreutils *parallel*:

  ```
  $ parallel -j16 ./task -- {0..127}
  ```
- Use Make:

  ```
  $ make -j16 {0..127}
  ```

  Makefile (not sure if standard or GNU Make-specific):

  ```
  .PHONY: $(MAKECMDGOALS)
  %:
      ./task $@
  ```
- Write your own:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env bash
  inputs=( {0..127} )
  nproc=16
  njobs=0
  for input in "${inputs[@]}"; do
      until (( njobs < nproc )); do
          wait -n; (( --njobs ))
      done
      ./task "$input"& (( ++njobs ))
  done
  while (( njobs )); do
      wait -n; (( --njobs ))
  done
  ```

Comment: GNU Parallel defaults to `:::` instead of `--` these days. Fun trivia: GNU Parallel was originally a wrapper around `make`: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/history.html

Comment: @OleTange: Aha, it looks like I looked at the manpage of _moreutils_ paralell (which still uses `--`) rather than GNU parallel.

Comment: Having started a queue with `parallel`, is it possible to change the list of jobs to be processed? Or to cancel some later jobs without aborting the ones being run right now?

Comment: @JonathanMichaelFoonlanTsang https://zenodo.org/record/1146014 Read section 7.8 and 7.9.